# Cannot connect to MySQL database after upgrade to version 8.0

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, mysql, mysql-workbench

I upgraded both MySQL work-bench to version 8.0 and MySQL server to version 8.0.15. I restarted my computer and I opened the workbench. I found my old connection. When I click test connection I get successful result.

[image]

When I double click on my connection I get this error message.

[image]

I tried to login to the MySQL server using and reset the password:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Please, what could be the problem?
I forgot what was the port number when I set up the connection in the old... version.

EDIT:

In the terminal, this is an attempt and it seems working. Just the workbench which I used to work from. Note that I use Ubunut 18.04:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 37
Server version: 8.0.15 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Comment: clear the old connection settings in workbench and add the new one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### From Commentz:

The error message you're getting is:

```
The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') doesn't exist.
```

To solve this, run,

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
mysql_install_db
```

in terminal. If doesn't solve the problem, run

```sql
> create user 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost';
```

in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL v8.0 has changed the authentification protocol:
On v8.0 it's using a `caching_sha2_password`.
Before it was `mysql_native_password`.

To create new user on previous version it was:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'rootV5'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

To create new user on v8.0 running this commands below (replace root and password by you're own of course !) :

```
CREATE USER 'rootV8'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'rootV8'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

To change the password encryption from old version user:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';
```

I hope you fix your problem with that :)

Comment: I tried this: `CREATE USER 'rootV8'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` and this `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';` and got: `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.role_edges' doesn't exist`

Comment: Did you try to log on workbench with you rootV8 user ?

Comment: No. In the command you give, I replace rootV8 with root. Is rootV8 a default user? And how to login with rootV8 in mySQL workbench? can you provide steps? Because when I click on the connection I get the error, so when will I try to enter this user?

Comment: To get back to you're old root config run <br>
`ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`
I'm not in my good computer to answered about workbench step... <br>
But you can create any user as you went. keep the root runing on previsous version if you downgrad mySQL and creat a new rootV8 to

Comment: I tried to run the ALTER command you gave me: I get this:`ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.role_edges' doesn't exist`

Comment: Did you run `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';` <br> or `ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';` ?

Comment: The first one. However, the problem has been solved by running `mysql_upgrade -u root -p` in the ubuntu terminal.